# multi-dimensional array element validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using an multi-dimensional set of input elements Like :

```
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[23][0]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(23,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[23][0]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[24][0]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(24,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[24][0]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[25][0]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(25,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[25][0]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[23][15]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(23,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[23][15]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[24][15]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(24,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[24][15]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[25][15]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(25,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[25][15]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[23][16]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(23,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[23][16]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[24][16]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(24,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[24][16]" class="imputText2"/>
<input value="0" name="Base_fare[25][16]" onchange="javascript:basechanged(25,0)" type="text" id="Base_fare[25][16]" class="imputText2"/>
```

i have stored the values to array by :

```
var Base_fare = new Array(3);
Base_fare[23] = new Array(4);
Base_fare[23][0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[23][0]').value);
Base_fare[23][15]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[23][15]').value);
Base_fare[23][16]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[23][16]').value);
Base_fare[23][17]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[23][17]').value);
Base_fare[24] = new Array(4);
Base_fare[24][0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[24][0]').value);
Base_fare[24][15]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[24][15]').value);
Base_fare[24][16]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[24][16]').value);
Base_fare[24][17]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[24][17]').value);
```

as the index were dynamic generated with php for-each loop
so i have to use     `$.each`

```
$.each(Base_fare, function(key, value) {
    alert(key);
  });
```

but it not returning 23 24 it is returning 1,2,3 like that
i need to validate those finds

what i want to do is sum thing like this

```
$.each(Base_fare, function(key, value) {
        $.each(Base_fare[key], function(key2, value2) {
    alert(key2 + ':' + value2);
     });
  });
```

so i can get each element's value to manipulate it and validate the fields but it is not working..

can any one give me any solution or alternative solution .

Comment: is it returning 1,2,3 or 0,1,2,3... ?  And if you alert key, does it alert the value itself, which would be, say a comma list of `parseFloat(document.getElementById('Base_fare[23][0]').value)`'s?

Comment: thanks for catching my mistake on this question actually the out put i mentioned that is with  alert(kay); what i want to do is sum thing like this $.each(Base_fare, function(key, value) {
  $.each(Base_fare[key], function(key2, value2) {
    alert(key2 + ':' + value2);
  });
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it not returning 23 24 it is returning 1,2,3 like that

jQuery's `each()` will iterate over the array using a `for` loop up to the array's `length`, exactly like this:

```
// actual jQuery's each() code
var i = 0, isArray = isArraylike( obj );
...
if ( isArray ) {
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) { // <------------------------------------ HERE
        value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

        if ( value === false ) {
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
...
```

So there is no way to begin iterating at the `23` and `24` indexes, like you want.
Your alternative is testing the index before using it:

```
$.each(Base_fare, function(key, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) alert(value);
});
```